# Passing Promise to first argument of `.then`

Tags: es6-promise

My question is: **Is it okay to pass a promise to the first argument of `.then`?** *(Assuming that I'm not interested in the returned value of the previous promise and I just want to chain promises together).*

> Someone told me that if I do this, a new promise will be created
>   implicitly (unnecessarily), and I might face issues handling errors
>   bellow in the promise chain.

I know that if you don't explicitly return a promise in an async method the result will be implicitly wrapped. In this case, `.then` should not wrap the argument in a promise since the argument is already a promise :/

Example:

```js
async function asyncFunc() {
  //async function (return Promise)
}

// I know this is okay
somePromise.then(() => asyncFunc());

// BUT... is this okay?
somePromise.then(asyncFunc());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it okay to pass a promise to the first argument of `.then`?

Yes.

> Someone told me that if I do this, a new promise will be created implicitly (unnecessarily)

`Promise.prototype.then()` returns a *new* promise either way.

> ```
> // BUT... is this okay?
> somePromise.then(asyncFunc());
> ```

No, it is more or less the same as:

```
const p = asyncFunc()
somePromise.then(p);
```

You execute the function before `somePromise` actually resolves. What you probably want instead is `somePromise.then(asyncFunction)`. This will properly chain the promises after each other.

> Someone told me that [...] I might face issues handling errors bellow in the promise chain.

No. This does not change the behaviour of the promise chain as long as long as there is a `catch` at the end of the chain.